# Where in memory are string literals ? stack / heap?

Tags: c, pointers, char, heap-memory, stack-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

As far as I know,

> generally, pointer have to be
>   allocated by malloc(), and will be allocated
>   to heap, then unallocated by free();

and

> non pointer(int,char,float,etc..) will be
>   allocated automatically to stack, and
>   unallocated as long as the function go to
>   return

but, from following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *a;

a = "tesaja";

return 0;
}
```

where will `a` allocated to ? stack or heap ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go

Comment: In your example, "tesaja" is called a string literal.  The text is constant, a.k.a. read-only, and could be placed anywhere.  It could be placed in the executable area *and copied* to writeable memory.  The actual location depends on the compiler settings and the platform.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The string [literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_science)) will be allocated in [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment). The pointer to it, `a`, will be allocated on the stack.

Your code will eventually get transformed by the compiler into something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const static char literal_constant_34562[7] = {'t', 'e', 's', 'a', 'j', 'a', '\0'};

int main()
{
    char *a;

    a = &literal_constant_34562[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, the exact answer to your question is: **neither**. *Stack*, *data*, *bss* and *heap* are all different regions of memory. Const static initialized variables will be in *data*.

Comment: Maybe. If binaries on your platform have one.

Comment: @capede And *non pointer(int,char,float,etc..) will allocated automatically to stack* is wrong. A pointer is a variable, a container, and its size depends on the size of a memory address. Its allocation (the pointer, not the address to which it points to) follows the same rule as the other variables, depending on where they are declared.

Comment: @ring0 : what do you mean of `where they're declared` ? inside function and outside function ?

Comment: @capede yes for instance. Inside a function, a block, as a parameter, as global variable..., but also as static, as volatile... The compiler decides in each case how it has to handle the variable space allocation.

Comment: do you have any idea where i can get documentation about `variable in space allocation` ?

Comment: There is another region of memory: *executable*.  This is where the processor instructions are stored.  Some compilers may place data into the executable region, especially constants.  There is no standard that requires string literals placed into a *data* segment.

Comment: what is `executable region of memory` called ? is that `stack` ? or there is no specific name, just `executable region of memory` ?

Comment: @capede, you really *need* to write a program in assembler. This way you will understand memory segmentation very good.

Comment: i will entering world of assembler soon after being monk on C :D

Answer (score 11):

`a` itself (the pointer) is defined as a local variable (implicitly) using the `auto` storage class, so it's allocated on the stack (or whatever memory the implementation uses for stack-like allocation -- some machines, such as IBM mainframes and the first Crays, don't have a "stack" in the normal sense).

The string literal "tesaja" is allocated statically. Exactly where that will be depends on the implementation -- some put it with other data, and some put it in a read-only data segment. A few treat all data as read/write and all code as read-only. Since they want they string literal to be read-only, they put it in the code segment.