# add in a char* some other data c code

Tags: c, nullpointerexception, char, strcpy

I have this part in a code:

```
char* data="My name is: ";
```

I would like to add to this the `argv[1]` argument with represents a name. How to do this in c code? I've tried `strcpy` and `strcat` but i have segmentation fault when Ipcp do this:

```
strcpy(data,argv[1]);
```

Can anyone please help?

Also why this: `data=data+argv[1]` is not working?

Comment: You **must not** modify a string literal. Copy it first in your own buffer and then modify it to append the new data.Good Read: [What is the difference between char a\[\] = “string”; and char *p = “string”;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460260/what-is-the-difference-between-char-a-string-and-char-p-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide some memory, where the result of the concatentation can be stored into. For example:

```
char buffer[1024];

strcpy(buffer, "My name is: ");
strcat(buffer, argv[1]);
```

Note, however, that this is error prone: if the value of `argv[1]` combined with the prefix string is longer than 1024 characters, this produces a buffer overflow. So, maybe something like this:

```
char* prefix = "My name is: ";
int length = strlen(prefix) + strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
char* buffer = malloc(length);

if (!buffer) abort();
else 
{
    strcpy(buffer, prefix);
    strcat(buffer, argv[1]);

    /* Do something with buffer here. And don't
     * forget to free it, once you no longer need
     * it. This is C -- no garbage collection. */

    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed examples. You can also use strncpy/strncat to avoid buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Memory for `data` will be allocated in read-only section. so modifying will cause issue.

[where in memory are string literals ? stack / heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970823/where-in-memory-are-string-literals-stack-heap)

`+` operator will not do concat as you thought.

`strcat()` function is implemented in `string.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Also why this: data=data+argv[1] is not working?

About this one - in C data and argv are nothing more than pointers to address in the memory containing your string. You can't concatenate strings(char*) this way.
I suggest to take a look at the string library and maybe a bit more in C as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You cant append to th data pointer because there are no space in it

```
char result_data [1024];
char* data="My name is: ";
strcat(result_data, data);
strcat(result_data, argv[1]);
```