# Where is a char-pointing string stored LOGICALLY?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, stack

In C, We can use char * to point at a string. Just like

```
char *s = "Hello";
```

.

As it be seen, Neither the variable is located dynamically on heap because there is no any dynamical functions like malloc, nor it is defined to point a certain other variable.

So my question is, **Where is the literal string which variable [char *s] points to stored logically?**

Is it stored in stack like any normal local variables? or, something like stack?

---

Actually, I am a graduate of Computer engineering department, but I haven't found and have been too much curious about how [char * string] works logically. It is a really great honor to ask right this one now.

Comment: It is stored in text segment

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy Not necessarily. Many platforms put string literals in the `rodata` section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where in memory are string literals ? stack / heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970823/where-in-memory-are-string-literals-stack-heap)

Comment: @MaggiePhillips You really need to clarify your question body. Where `s` is stored and where what it *points to* is stored can be radically different, and you're likely to get a smattering of answers to both, most of which will be speculative regarding `s`, as you've not shown the context in which it exists. (global, local, static-local??).

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, I certainly need to divide the variable s and the string position. What I am really curious about is the position of the literal string "Hello". Thx.

Comment: What is "logically" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 13):

The variable `char* s` is stored on the stack, assuming it's declared in a function body. If it is declared in a class, then it is stored wherever the object for the class is stored. If it is declared as a global, then it is stored in global memory.

In fact, any non-`static` and non-`thread_local` variable you declare in these three positions behave the same way, regardless of whether it is a primitive (i.e. `int`), an object (i.e. `vector<int>`), or a pointer (i.e. `const char*`). 
If a variable is static, it is always stored in global space. If a variable is `thread_local`, each thread gets its own copy, and that copy will usually stored at the base of the stack for the corresponding thread.

The actual string `"Hello"`, which `s` points to, is stored in a constant global space somewhere, usually the `.data` segment.

Comment: Where `s` is stored depends on where it's defined. It's usually stored on the stack if it's a local (inside a function or block), but not if it's global variable. Besides, it doesn't *have* to be stored on the stack, the C specification doesn't actually specify where local variables should be stored, it only specifies the variables scope and lifetime.

Comment: Well, I am now a little bit to remember the basics on 'Operating System' study in my college. I guess I have ever scribbled the "text" segment once, then I seem to check that book again. Thx.

Comment: This answer is very implementation-specific. Some implentations don't have text segments, stacks, and so on.

Comment: Notice that many platforms have a special `rodata` segment for read-only global variables. It differs from `text` in that the content of `rodata` cannot be executed on machines that support marking some memory areaas as non-executable.

Answer (score 3):

String literals have *static storage duration*. That means they exist for the whole lifetime of your program.  They may be stored in a non-writable area, and they may overlap with other string literals.  Two different instances of the same literal may or may not coincide.

It is up to your implementation (compiler/linker/etc). to make a decision that complies with those requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about `s`, it's a pointer, it points somewhere. It has *automatic storage duration* just like any other local variable not declared `static`. What's “special” though is the string literal you are pointing to.

You can think of a string literal like `"foo"` as an *unnamed global variable* with some special constraints. These constraints are:

- You cannot write to the string literal, as if it was declared as `const`
- Two string literals might share the same address or overlap