# Issue when printing char buffer

Tags: c

I want to store the filename path in a `char` variable and pass it later via function call. To do so, I declared the following char buffer:

```
char *filename_path =  malloc(100* sizeof(char));
```

Now, to test that, I assigned it using a path followed by printing the value of the buffer to make sure it fits well.

```
filename_path= "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s";
printf("%s\n", filename_path);
...
free(filename_path);
```

However, I get this error :

```
../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s
k.out(1154,0x7fff9843c3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x103fbbacb: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Can someone hint me where the issue could be? Thank you

Comment: You're only allowed to `free` pointers returned by `malloc`.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for your answer. Can you please show how to free in this case!

Comment: `p = malloc(...); p = ...` is a memory leak. You're overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc`.

Comment: `filename_path= "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s";` --> `strcpy(filename_path, "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I like your way. Very clean! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
filename_path= "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s";
```

does not copy the contents of the string literal to the memory pointed to by `filename_path`; it *overwrites* the value of `filename_path` with the address of the string literal.  You're basically throwing away the value returned from `malloc`, leading to a) a memory leak, and b) the error when calling `free`.

Instead of using the assignment operator, use the `strcpy` function:

```
strcpy( filename_path, "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overwriting the pointer returned by malloc with a new, constant string (the `filename_path = "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s"` line). It is, then, trying to free it.

You can't do that, because the pointer is not the same as the one returned by malloc anymore.

To copy your contents into your malloc'ed string, you should use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/).

Like this:

```
char *filename_path =  malloc(100* sizeof(char)); 

strncpy(filename_path, "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s", 100);
printf("%s\n", filename_path);

free(filename_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to save your original pointer in order to free it:

So store a temporary pointer and free that instead.

```
char *filename_path ,*temp_path; 
filename_path  =  malloc(100* sizeof(char));
temp_path = filename_path;

//your code for filename_path

free(temp_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way:

1. You are allocating 100 bytes of memory and assigning the `filename_path` pointer to point to that allocated memory.
2. You now *change* `filename_path` to point to the static string "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s".
3. Since you changed where `filename_path` points to, you no longer have a pointer to the memory you allocated earlier and no longer have any way to free it.
4. When you attempt to free `filename_path` you are actually attempting to free the static string "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s" which of course as the error message says, was not actually allocated by malloc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is memory location of `malloc()` versus a string literal such as `filename_path= "../Datasets/Cluster(%d)%s";`

`malloc()` allocates memory on the **heap** and returns a pointer to that memory. String literals are located somewhere else entirely -- usually in static/data(see this post for more info [where in memory are string literals ? stack / heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970823/where-in-memory-are-string-literals-stack-heap))

Since you assigned `filename_path` to point to somewhere other than where you malloced, you are unable to free it.