# Memory fault and pointer to string

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, malloc

So I'm trying to reverse a string, but I get a memory fault. Memory for s and s1 is initialized enough to accomodate the '/0' character as well.

Interestingly if I remove *s=*s1 and print s1 instead the program works.
But I haven't even set the "\0" character at the end of s1 so how does it even know where to stop printing?

And in the case below what exactly is the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
    char *s = "abcdefghijklmnop", *s1=malloc(17);
    int i;  
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        *(s1+i) = *(s+strlen(s)-1-i);
    }
    *s=*s1;
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the difference between `*s = *s1` and `s = s1` is?

Comment: the former takes the value s1 points to and puts it in the address s points to, while the latter makes s point to what s1 points to

Comment: @ScottHunter: Okay I see why that should work. But what's wrong in *s = *s1

Comment: you cannot write into memory associated with *s.

Comment: Every time you feel like writing `*(p + i)` for some pointer `p` and index `i`, just write `p[i]` instead. It's much easier to read, and means the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char *s = "abcdefghijklmnop"` is a string literal which is often in read-only memory.
An error will be generated if you attempt to modify a string literal.

You attempt to replace the first character in `s` with the first character in `s1`  when you do `*s=*s+1`.

If `s` wasn't a string literal, you should've done `s=s1` instead of `*s=*s1` to make `s` its reverse.

More about this:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/why-are-c-string-literals-read-only 
[String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go) 
[where in memory are string literals ? stack / heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970823/where-in-memory-are-string-literals-stack-heap)

The correct string is printed with `printf("%s", s1);` even if no `\0` was stored because the memory next to the last character just happened to be `0` which is equivalent to `\0`. This needn't always be so and *cannot* be relied upon as [`malloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) doesn't initialise the memory that it allocates.

But [`calloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) *will* initialise the memory it allocates to `0`.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029584/why-does-malloc-initialize-the-values-to-0-in-gcc/8029624#8029624).

Comment: Ok, so actually *s = *s1 only replaces the first character? Not the entire string?

Comment: @CodeChef123 That's right. If `s` wasn't a string literal and could be modified, you should've done `s=s1`. And don't forget to deallocate the memory for `s1` with `free(s1)`.

Comment: So you're saying the address s is pointing to is in ROM? Is there any reason for this, as it seems more logical for it to be like a normal pointer(*ints, for e.g.)

Comment: And for the 2nd part of my question if I remove *s=*s1 and print s1 how does the program know when to stop printing because I haven't supplied the \0 character

Comment: About the first part, see links in the answer I just added. About the second part, the memory adjacent to the last character probably just happened to be `0` which is equivalent to `\0` denoting the end of string. You _cannot_ rely on this as `malloc()` won't initialise the memory it allocates. But `calloc()` will initialise its memory with `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `*s=*s1` only copy the first content of s1 into s. i.e, `*(s+0)=*(s1+0)` not the entire string. So we need to assign the address of s1 to s. i.e, `s=s1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main()
{
    char *s = "abcdefghijklmnop", *s1=malloc(17);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        *(s1+i) = *(s+strlen(s)-1-i);
    }
    s=s1;
    printf("%s",s);
    free(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

**It is good practice to free the memory after its use.**